# Python Hamcrest - test that list is not empty

Tags: python, hamcrest

Is there a clean way to test that a list is not empty in Hamcrest (python).  There are several ways to do it by checking the list length etc., but I'd like something that reads nicely for tests.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `empty` matcher:

```
assert_that(mylist, is_not(empty()))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't import empty, it doesn't appear to exist in pyhamcrest.

Comment: Looks like hamcrest/library/collection/__init__.py is missing ``from is_empty import empty``. Make that fix, then submit a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way with the best readability is probably something like:

```
from hamcrest import assert_that, is_, empty, not_

assert_that([], is_(not_(empty())))
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using `assertNotEqual([], list)` to check if the list isn't empty